# Python : javabridge virtual machine only works once

Tags: python, virtual-machine

I need to use bioformats-python to read microscope images. To use it a Java VM is needed.

**I can only use java VM once**, if I execute again my python script I get an error.

**If I restart the spyder kernel, the script works only once again.**

I installed the JDK (8u181) and setted up the path variables.
I use Spyder with python 3.6.

Here is the code I used to test the java VM :

```
import javabridge

javabridge.start_vm(run_headless=True)
try:
    print(javabridge.run_script('java.lang.String.format("Hello, %s!", greetee);',
                                dict(greetee='world')))
finally:
    javabridge.kill_vm()
```

What I obtained the first time of execution :

```
>>> Hello, world!
```

And this is the **error message** I get when I try to run it a second time :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Z820\Miniconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\javabridge\jutil.py", line 281, in start_thread
    env = vm.create(args)
  File "_javabridge.pyx", line 653, in _javabridge.JB_VM.create
RuntimeError: Failed to create Java VM. Return code = -1
Failed to create Java VM
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-81778b2b637e>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Z820/Desktop/Python/Fichier_Python/Projet_correlation/Replace Fiji/usebioformas.py', wdir='C:/Users/Z820/Desktop/Python/Fichier_Python/Projet_correlation/Replace Fiji')

  File "C:\Users\Z820\Miniconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 678, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Z820\Miniconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 106, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Z820/Desktop/Python/Fichier_Python/Projet_correlation/Replace Fiji/usebioformas.py", line 10, in <module>
    javabridge.start_vm(run_headless=True)

  File "C:\Users\Z820\Miniconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\javabridge\jutil.py", line 314, in start_vm
    raise RuntimeError("Failed to start Java VM")

RuntimeError: Failed to start Java VM
```

If I try to launch it a third time, I get a slightly different error message.

Does anyone have an idea to solve this problem ?

I thank you in advance for your help,

Thomas.

Answer (score 1):

That is a limitation of JVM, you can use only once start_vm().

See this link for more information
https://github.com/LeeKamentsky/python-javabridge/issues/88

Answer (score 0):

The issue is similar to this:

https://jpype.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html#unloading-the-jvm

> Unloading the JVM
>
> The JNI API defines a method called destroyJVM().
> However, this method does not work. That is, Sun’s JVMs do not allow
> unloading. For this reason, after calling shutdownJVM(), if you
> attempt calling startJVM() again you will get a non-specific
> exception. There is nothing wrong (that I can see) in JPype. So if Sun
> gets around to supporting its own properly, or if you use JPype with a
> non-SUN JVM that does (I believe IBM’s JVMs support JNI invocation,
> but I do not know if their destroyJVM works properly), JPype will be
> able to take advantage of it. As the time of writing, the latest
> stable Sun JVM was 1.4.2_04.

Answer (score 0):

I have found irritating but yet working solution for: "RuntimeError: Failed to start Java VM." Note: This solution is for Google Colab Notebook only, maybe other notebooks have also this option, never mind.
You just have to go to 'Runtime' tab and click 'Restart runtime' and it will restart and JVM will work once more.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jbo5y.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here [JVM issue](https://github.com/LeeKamentsky/python-javabridge/issues/88#issuecomment-817875968), multiprocessing solves the issue. For example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def my_function(arg1):
  ###
  Code requiring JVM
  ###

if __name__ == "__main__":
  p = Process(target=my_function, args=(arg1))
  p.start()
  p.join()  # this blocks until the process terminates
```